# D3 Javascript - Repeat a group of shapes with data bind

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to repeat a group of shapes specifically
text rect text circles
Where in circles is again a repeat of circle

My data is

```
Jsondata =[
{ "name":"A", "WidthOfRect":50, "justAnotherText":"250", "numberOfCircles" :3 }, 
{ "name":"B", "WidthOfRect":150, "justAnotherText":"350","numberOfCircles" :2 },
{ "name":"C", "WidthOfRect":250, "justAnotherText":"450","numberOfCircles" :1 }]
```

Basically Out of this data i am trying to construct a customized bar chart.

The width of the rect is based upon the data widthofrect from the json, as well as number of circles is based upon numberofcircles property.

I looked out for a number of options to repeat group of shapes but couldn't find one.

Comment: If you are trying to loop through your array a simple for loop or Array.forEach will do.

Comment: Yeah i can do it with a loop, but is there any other way, the selectall automatically appends shapes for the length of the data hence was thinking on using that and somehow removing the loop. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Sorry no idea about any such libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're right in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746974/d3-javascript-repeat-a-group-of-shapes-with-data-bind/49749829#comment86511462_49746974): do **not** use loops to append elements in a D3 code. Also, your supposition about the length of the data is correct.

Back to the question:

The text and rect part is pretty basic, D3 101, so let's skip that. The circles is the interesting part here.

My proposed solution involves using `d3.range` to create an array whose number of elements (or length) is specified by `numberOfCircles`. That involves two selections.

First, we create the groups (here, `scale` is, obviously, a scale):

```
var circlesGroups = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(20," + scale(d.name) + ")"
  });
```

And then we create the circles. Pay attention to the `d3.range`:

```
var circles = circlesGroups.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.range(d.numberOfCircles)
  })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  //etc...
```

Here is a demo, I'm changing the `numberOfCircles` in your data to paint more circles:

```js
var width = 500,
  height = 200;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var data = [{
    "name": "A",
    "WidthOfRect": 50,
    "justAnotherText": "250",
    "numberOfCircles": 13
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "WidthOfRect": 150,
    "justAnotherText": "350",
    "numberOfCircles": 22
  },
  {
    "name": "C",
    "WidthOfRect": 250,
    "justAnotherText": "450",
    "numberOfCircles": 17
  }
];

var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.name
  }))
  .range([20, height - 20])
  .padding(0.5);

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var circlesGroups = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(20," + scale(d.name) + ")"
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.name)
  })

var circles = circlesGroups.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.range(d.numberOfCircles)
  })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 10 + 12 * d
  });

var axis = d3.axisLeft(scale)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(20,0)"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

PS: I'm using D3 v5.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks a lot.